# Factory facility in Simple Injector

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, simple-injector

I am migrating from `Windsor` to `Simple Injector`, I tried to follow the following [this link](https://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Castle%20Windsor&referringTitle=Migration%20Guide). But I could not find any replacement for:

```
container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();
container.Register(Component.For<ICacheDependencyFactory>().AsFactory());
```

What will be the replacement the above code in `Simple Injector`?

Edited:

**ICacheDependencyFactory.cs**

```
public interface ICacheDependencyFactory
{
    T Create<T>()
       where T : ICacheDependency;

    void Release<T>(T cacheDependency)
        where T : ICacheDependency;
}
```

Comment: That link is the opposite of what you are describing, it is how to migrate ***to*** CastleWindsor.

Comment: Yeah I know but still there is a lot of guidance.

Comment: it's also out of date; it was Last edited Oct 6, 2012 , and is referring to Code samples based on version 2.5.3. The current version of Simple Injector is 3.0.0.; the previous 2.x release was 2.8.1.

Comment: Yes that's the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Castle's factory facility is able to generate a proxy class based on the interface you supply. This proxy class will call back into the container to request the creation of a new instance of such type.

Simple Injector lacks such feature. Simple Injector doesn't implement this, because:

- The number of factories your application code needs, should be fairly limited (to just a couple at most).
  Well designed applications hardly need factories.
- It's really easy to implement this with a hand-written factory.
- Hand-written factories should be part of your [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) (where there already is a dependency on the container). This prevents application code from having to take a dependency on the container.

Here's an example:

```
private sealed class CacheDependencyFactory : ICacheDependencyFactory {
    public Container Container { get; set; }
    public T Create<T>() where T : ICacheDependency, class {
        return this.Container.GetInstance<T>();
    }
}
```

This factory can be registered as follows:

```
container.RegisterSingle<ICacheDependencyFactory>(
    new CacheDependencyFactory { Container = container });
```

Comment: I am copying from the following link: http://geekswithblogs.net/Rhames/archive/2012/09/13/adding-sql-cache-dependencies-to-the-loosely-coupled-.net-cache.aspx 
And there is no concrete class for ICacheDependencyFactory.

Comment: You can make the implementation yourself.

Comment: And do note that the `Release` method is redundant in Simple Injector as explained [here](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/decisions.html#never-force-release). And even with Windsor, I would argue against having a `Release` method on your factories, because it means you are leaking implementation details about the IoC library into your core domain. Even with Windsor you can do without forcing this constraint upon your application, although it would take a bit more work to do so with Windsor.

Comment: This is big disadvantage that there's no such thing as Typed Factory Facility. 

No mater how fast container is if it can do everyday job it is useless, like formula 1 racing car for travelling.
I want to declare an interface with Create method and get it working without implementing anything especially I don't want to have direct dependencies to concrete IOC. I also want to declare an interface method which might get parameters which will be used for constructing a certain object.

Comment: @user1335696. Please look into the concept of the Composition Root. Factories should be 3 defined inside your composition root. This prevents your application to take a dependency on the container.

Comment: @Steven. You missed my point I don't want anything to be defined or implemented. I want to declare interface, say to container "Hey, this is a factory and when someone calls create method just resolve a component the way  component was registered". Not clear how Composition Root can help me here.

Comment: @user1325696: But you missed my point. If you apply DI correctly, you will hardly need any factories anymore. And those few factories that you still need, can be written with just a few lines of code. This code can be placed in the same location as where you configure your container; a place where you already have a dependency on the container. My point is: if you need Factory Facility features to keep your code maintainable: you are doing it wrong.

Comment: It is not constructive to say you're doing it wrong, just because it is not implemented in your container. The reality is that for old projects this is needed. You won't change my mind that I need 2 or more different or slightly differently configured implementations of the same interface. I believe named registration are required.